# Is there a better way to do element-wise operations on 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

I am required to do an element-wise summation on 2 arrays. Apart from using a nested loop, is there a more efficient way of doing it?

I am using JavaScript ES6.

I thought of using map, but map will always return an array of same length as the one it was called on.

I also consider using an object to store the sums, but I couldn't do it without nesting 2 for-loops at some point.

```
const arr1 = [1, 2];
const arr2 = [0, 3, 5];

const sum = [];

for (let x of arr1) {
  for (let y of arr2) {
    sum.push(x + y);
  }
}
// Expected output: [ 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 7 ]
```

The expected solution should be better than O(n^2).

Comment: I think complexity can't be better than O(n^2)

Comment: No matter what the syntax, you'll end up with some kind of nested loop. You could hardcode like the outer loop to handle multiple indexes at the same time, which would cut the execution time, but the time complexity itself stays the same. What is your use case or what do you need a more efficient algo for? There's probably some math algos with better complexity, but depending on the use case, you might be better off letting the server or multiple service workers do the nested loops on parts of arr1.

Comment: actually it's O(n*m). and it stays, because you need to visit each item by the count of the second array.

Comment: In that case I would go find the good ol' university linear algebra course and look through it to see if there's like matrix multiplication algorithms I could write in JS. Since it's a coding challenge, there must be algos out there that do this more efficiently.

Comment: @Shilly It is related to this challenge here  (https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/microverse-coding-challenges/challenges/electronics-shop/submissions/code/1313619854)

So it got me thinking; what if one would face this kind of problem in a production environment, would there be a better way to solve it as the size of the arrays gets really big?

Comment: Maybe the people at maths.stackexchange.com can help better with this. And in production, I just use the nested loop, but share it across multiple workers on client side or just let the load balancer spawn whatever amount of processes it likes to have to take care of it server side. Unless you do big data, I haven't had a use case yet professionally where this kind of efficiency for one nested loop mattered and chunking the work wasn't possible.

Comment: @Shilly Great, thanks for your inputs. I really appreciate....and thanks to all of you guys too.

Comment: Do you need only unique sums or all?

Comment: In this use case, the unique sums are required though. Does it after the O(n) in any way?

Comment: It could, depending on the range. In this case, since `n` is small compared to the range (1000 << 10^6), we cannot improve on `O(n * m)`, which is the complexity listed in the HackerRank editorial. If the range were close to `n`, I believe we could get the unique sums in `O(n log n)` with a Fast Fourier Transform.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can create a list of lists, each inner list a result of mapping one of your input lists to an addition with one element from the other list.

```
const sums = [];

for (let x of arr1) {
  sums.push(arr2.map(function (y) { return y + x }))
}
```

You will then end up with one array containing *n* arrays full of results.  Access them with `sums[i][j]`.

This doesn't reduce complexity (it will still be *O*(*n*×*m*), and I'm certain that this is inevitable) but it moves some of the computation from JS code into the `map` implementation which probably is more efficient (optimized in the browser's JS implementation, etc.).

This will be more effective if `arr1` is smaller than `arr2`, so you might consider swapping them before applying this idea.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not into JS so much.  I guess just the `return` was missing.  Added that.  Please check again.  (If everything works, feel free to remove your comment, then I will do as well, this will keep the comments section small.)